# "I am going based off of that statistic"?

Tags: word-usage

Is the following correct?

> I am going **based off of** that statistic"?

If not what's a good way of phrasing the intended meaning and when can "based off of" be used?

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to include the intended meaning, in case your example is wrong and unintelligible.

Comment: alright then give me a sentence with based off that makes sense so I can better understand its meaning and applications. I also dont know a substitute, go is probably the wrong verb choice.

Comment: I don't think the example is so bad, but I think you're combining two different phrasings.  I would say either "Going off that statistic..." or "Based off that statistic..."

Comment: @ChadThunder your sentence is wordy but native English speakers talk like that all the time. However, as stangdon mentions in his comment above, it would be better style to use one or the other of those phrases.

Comment: Based **on**, not _"off of"._ See [this related question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15081/based-on-instead-of-based-off-of).

Comment: @Max - I disagree that it's wrong and unintelligible; I'd characterize it as contrived and needing context. But it's not all that hard to think of one: Q: _Are you going to next month Expo for Doodads and Widgets?_ A: _I've heard that it's the most popular Expo in North America. I am going based off of that statistic._ That said, I agree with your overall sentiment – there's not really enough info here to say much about it, and Chad would do well to read about [Details, Please...](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. I didn't mean to suggest that this example was wrong. I just meant in general, it's a good idea to include the "intended meaning". Often a user posts an example and asks how to improve it, but it's impossible because we don't have the intended meaning. Actually, I thought it sounded fine. It didn't even occur to me that it could be considered wordy! I can easily imagine people saying that. That said, we can't say for sure that this example matches OP's "intended meaning", although it's likely. Users should read "Details, Please" as suggested.

Comment: related http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/based-off-versus-based-on